# Scrollviewer having issues with Dockpanel

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer, dockpanel

[image: http://images.temppic.com/28-11-2011/images_vertis/1322454731_0.87909400.png]

I'm using a Dockpanel as my main panel for my layout. The toolbar on top is set to top, while the side panel is set to left. The documentviewer is set to fill by LastChildFill.

The problem is that the height of the scrollviewer doesn't scale as the window resizes. Only the documentviewer does. It seems to only scale as the child content increases. I'm trying to mimic Google Chrome's Print layout. When the children does not overflow the window then there is no scrollbar but if it's less than the window, the scrollbars would fill up the window.

Here's the code:

```
<ToolBar Width="Auto" Height="35" DockPanel.Dock="Top" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Panel.ZIndex="10" Background="White">

<StackPanel Margin="5,0,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Button Content="New" Style="{StaticResource MenuItem}"/>
    <Button Content="Save" Style="{StaticResource MenuItem}"/>
    <Button Content="Print" Style="{StaticResource MenuItem}"/>
    <Button Content="Delete" Style="{StaticResource MenuItem}"/>
    <Button Content="Export" Style="{StaticResource MenuItem}"/>
    <Border Style="{StaticResource SeparatorStyle}"/>
    <Button Content="Burn DVD" Style="{StaticResource MenuItem}"/>
    <Button Content="Open Folder" Style="{StaticResource MenuItem}"/>
    <Border Style="{StaticResource SeparatorStyle}"/>
    <Button Content="Next Patient" Style="{StaticResource MenuItem}"/>
</StackPanel> 

</ToolBar>

<ScrollViewer Background="White" x:Name="SidePanel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Panel.ZIndex="2" Padding="10">
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,10,0,0"/>
    </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
<Label Content="Patient Report" Style="{StaticResource SidePanel_H1}" />
<Rectangle Style="{StaticResource SidePanel_HR}" />
<TextBox Text="DATA"/>
<TextBox Text="DATA"/>
<TextBox Text="DATA"/>
<TextBox Text="DATA"/>
<TextBox Text="DATA"/>
<TextBox Text="DATA"/>
<TextBox Text="DATA"/>
<TextBox Text="DATA"/>
<TextBox Text="DATA"/>
<TextBox Text="DATA"/>
<TextBox Text="DATA"/>
<TextBox Text="DATA"/>
<TextBox Text="DATA"/>
<TextBox Text="DATA"/>
<TextBox Text="DATA"/>

</StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>

<Rectangle Height="Auto" Width="2" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Fill="#FFA0A0A0"/>

<DocumentViewer x:Name="dv1" AllowDrop="False" Cursor="Hand" Loaded="dv1_Loaded" MinWidth="600">
    <FixedDocument Focusable="False" x:Name="FD">
    </FixedDocument>
</DocumentViewer>


</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"` or remove the attribute and you'll be fine.

`DockPanel` affects only one direction for docked children. In your case, it's horizontal.

Comment: Thanks! That worked really well. Though in addition, is there a simple way to takeout the scrollbars if the content doesn't overflow yet? Sort of like visible if needed.

Comment: See [HorizontalScrollbarVisibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.horizontalscrollbarvisibility.aspx) and [VerticalScrollbarVisibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.verticalscrollbarvisibility.aspx)